Convert WPF DataGrid to Avalonia DataGrid

How to change cell style and add trigger

<DataGrid x:Name="datagrid1" BorderBrush="Purple" BorderThickness="3">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="5">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>


How to set column name in code behind, cannot add x:Name

<DataGrid x:Name="datagrid1" BorderBrush="Purple" BorderThickness="3">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="column1" Width="5*">


Get compile error to create datagrid style in App.axaml.
Not sure whether render is slow for large data. For WPF, I will set as below

<Style x:Key="DataGridStyle" Selector="DataGrid">
    <Setter Property="EnableColumnVirtualization" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="EnableRowVirtualization" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode" Value="Standard" />
</Style>

Isnt require these setting / do not need / is other setting for Avalonia DataGrid?

How to set style for datagrid that set at App.axaml

<DataGrid x:Name="datagrid1" Selector="{StaticResource DataGridStyle}">

For issue 1, there is change cell style from link.
But I want change individual column instead whole datagrid
For issue 2, 3 and 4 I cannot find resource
update:
I can change column cell style
<DataGrid.Styles>
    <Style Selector="DataGridCell.column1">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
    </Style>
    <Style Selector="DataGridCell.column2">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Styles>

<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="Auto" CellStyleClasses="column1">

